# Where to Find Ubuntu.Application and libhud1-dev

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

***libhud1-dev***
and also
***libhybris-dev***
and also 
***libubuntu-platform-api1-dev***

I am also looking for a full blown libary called ***Ubuntu.Applications*** You know like how there is ***Ubuntu.Components*** 
Seems Like I can not build all the apps for desktop with out these for new touch code.  I can not find them can you ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this moment I don't think we have a public PPA containing all the touch related packages used by our images. I know this will come later this week (together with the daily images), but for now you can grab them from the development branches:

- Libhybris: `lp:phablet-extras/libhybris`
- Ubuntu Platform API: `lp:platform-api`
- HUD: `lp:hud/phablet`

Now for the Ubuntu.* components, make sure you have the SDK installed at your system. Just go to http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ and follow the install procedure described there.

Comment: I just want to point out that it's probably a good idea to choose the mesa EGL drivers if libhybris is installed on a desktop or laptop. Just run `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf` (64 bit) or `sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf` (32 bit).